# Data Not Being Inserted Into SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I am programming a game that uses a SQLite database to store integer values that represent the resources the user has gained. I have an image button that when pressed calls a service using a handler as a timer. This timer adds a certain amount of resources to the user's total over a set time period. Problem is that when I try inserting the new data into the database, it does not insert correctly. The weird thing is that my original testing phone (running froyo) ran the insertions just fine. After switching to a phone with kitkat, it no longer inserts. I have run the sqlite3 tool and the database is being created correctly, all values just stay at zero. Reading also works from some tests I tried. Let me know if you see anything that I may be missing here because I have been stumped with this problem for weeks. Thanks guys.

Here is the code to the database where the table is created containing one row of data:

```
public class Database 
{
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ROCK = "amount_of_rock";
public static final String KEY_METEORROCK = "amount_of_meteor_rock";
public static final String KEY_WATER = "amount_of_water";
public static final String KEY_SHOVEL = "shovel_level";
public static final String KEY_SHOVELEXP = "shovel_experience";
public static final String KEY_BUCKET = "bucket_level";
public static final String KEY_BUCKETEXP = "bucket_experience";
public static final String KEY_PICKAXE = "pickaxe_level";
public static final String KEY_PICKAXEEXP = "pickaxe_experience";
public static final String KEY_POPULATION = "population";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "2023db";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "maintable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DbHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);      
    }//end DbHelper constructor

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        //create table
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_ROCK + " INTEGER, " + 
            KEY_METEORROCK + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_WATER + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_POPULATION + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_SHOVEL + " INTEGER, " + 
            KEY_BUCKET + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_PICKAXE + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_SHOVELEXP + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_BUCKETEXP + " INTEGER, " +
            KEY_PICKAXEEXP + " INTEGER);");
    }//end onCreate function

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }//end onUpgrade function
}//end DbHelper class

public Database(Context c)
{
    ourContext = c;
}//end Database constructor

public Database open() {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}//end Database open function

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}//end close function

public long rockAmountEntry(int rockAmount) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROCK, rockAmount);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, null, null);
}//end rockAmountEntry function

public int getRockAmount() {
    int rockAmount = 0, iRockAmount = 0;
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROCK, KEY_METEORROCK,
        KEY_WATER, KEY_POPULATION, KEY_SHOVEL, KEY_BUCKET, KEY_PICKAXE,
        KEY_SHOVELEXP, KEY_BUCKETEXP, KEY_PICKAXEEXP
    };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            iRockAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROCK);
            rockAmount = c.getInt(iRockAmount);
        }//end if
        c.close();
        return rockAmount;
    }//end if
    return 0;
}//end getRockAmount function
}//end Database
```

The user is given an imagebutton which they can click to gain resources. When it is clicked, it calls a service that runs a handler as a timer and adds a certain amount of rock to the database depending on the user's level.

Here is the code for the imagebutton as mentioned:

```
spaceRock1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.spaceRockButton1);
spaceRock1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {   
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attempting to Gain Resources", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //button cannot be clicked
        spaceRock1.setEnabled(false);

        //start service for timer
        startService(new Intent(runGraphics.this, SetupTimerSR1.class));

        //stop service for timer
        stopService(new Intent(runGraphics.this, SetupTimerSR1.class));

        //button can be clicked again
        mMessageReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
            {
                clickOnOff3 = intent.getBooleanExtra("spaceRock1Stat", false);
                spaceRock1.setEnabled(clickOnOff3);
                if (clickOnOff3)
                {
                    updateScores();
                }//end if
            }//end onReceive function
        };
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver3, new IntentFilter("spaceRock1Status"));

    }//end onClick function
});//end setOnClickListener
```

Here is the code to the service called when the imagebutton is pressed:

```
public class SetupTimerSR1 extends Service {
Handler handler;
Database data;
Intent i;
int pickLevel = 1, pickExpTotal = 0;
int rockAmount = 0, pickExp = 0, totalRock = 0;
int timerCount = 0;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}//end onBind function

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //setup 24 hour timer
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}//end onCreate function

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //check experience for current level
        if (pickExp < 3000) {
            pickLevel = 1;
        }//end if
        else if (pickExp > 3000 && pickExp < 6000) {
            pickLevel = 2;
        }//end else if
        else if (pickExp > 6000 && pickExp < 9000) {
            pickLevel = 3;
        }//end else if
        else if (pickExp > 9000 && pickExp < 12000) {
            pickLevel = 4;
        }//end else if
        else if (pickExp > 12000) {
            pickLevel = 5;
        }//end else if

        //give resource based on level
        if (pickLevel == 1) {
            rockAmount += 1;
            pickExp += 10;
        }//end if
        else if (pickLevel == 2) {
            rockAmount += 3;
            pickExp += 20;
        }//end else if
        else if (pickLevel == 3) {
            rockAmount += 4;
            pickExp += 30;
        }//end else if
        else if (pickLevel == 4) {
            rockAmount += 5;
            pickExp += 40;
        }//end else if
        else if (pickLevel == 5) {
            rockAmount += 7;
            pickExp += 50;
        }//end else if
        timerCount++;
        if (timerCount < 3) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        }//end if
        else {
            //pull data
            data = new Database(SetupTimerSR1.this);
            data.open();
            pickExpTotal = data.getPickExp();
            totalRock = data.getRockAmount();
            data.close();

            //add new data to old
            pickExpTotal += pickExp;
            totalRock += rockAmount;

            //push data
            data.open();
            data.pickExpEntry(pickExpTotal);
            data.rockAmountEntry(totalRock);
            data.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pickExp: " + pickExpTotal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total rock: " + totalRock, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            i.putExtra("spaceRock1Stat", true);

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }//end else
    }//end run function
};//end runnable    

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    i = new Intent("spaceRock1Status");
    i.putExtra("spaceRock1Stat", false);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i);
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}//end onStartCommand function
}//end SetupTimerSR1 class
```

Comment: Check that rockAmountEntry() is both receiving the argument that you expect it to receive, and that it's returning the correct value that you'd expect.

Comment: There is no place in your code where it inserts new data into the database.

Comment: @JDJ rockAmountEntry does receive the correct amount but the value in the database returned is zero.

Comment: @CL. Yes there is...the service calls functions that are in the database code where inserts are made.

Comment: The word `insert` appears nowhere in the code you've shown. Where do you insert?

Comment: @CL. In the database code, in the rockAmountEntry function I use content values to put the value in the database with an "ourDatabase.update" This is how I was shown to do it since using "ourDatabase.insert" creates multiple rows when this is only a single row table.

Comment: And where does that single row get created?

Comment: @CL. Code was added to the database area to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` method can change only rows that already exist in the table.
However, the app *never* inserts any row into the table.

The row should be added when the database is created:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        ...);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " DEFAULT VALUES");
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I wonder why it worked in Froyo without that statement.